# Use ErrorDocument in .htaccess when using friendly urls

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2, custom-error-pages, errordocument

I'm having some problems during the error handling of a webpage with friendly urls (and mod_rewrite) turned on in a **PHP 5.2 website**. I manage the url rules from a framework, so **I need to move all the requests to index.php**. That's the easy part (and works like a charm). Now, from the same framework I happen to throw http status codes to the header, and then I `exit()`, so no output but the headers is dispatched to the user. Now the problem is one of these (or both):

1. The status code is sent **after** the processing started, so Apache doesn't have anything to do with this (correct me if I am mistaken).
2. Every request (probably even 403 and 500?) is being rewritten to index.php, so `ErrorDocument` is never read, as everything looks normal (very probably mistaken)

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

ErrorDocument 400 /error/400
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
ErrorDocument 405 /error/405
ErrorDocument 408 /error/408
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500
ErrorDocument 502 /error/502
ErrorDocument 504 /error/504
```

Where `/error/"number"` is another URI I can parse, but it can be a static page, too.
Now, the question:

**Is there any way I can make these error requests (thrown *after* the request is started) to use the directives of `ErrorDocument`?**

PS: As a sidenote, Chrome shows a standard "chromy" Forbidden/Not Found/etc page, while Firefox just leaves a blank screen.

Comment: ErrorDocument is a directive so I am not sure I understand, but [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) is a link about Apache error responses that could be useful.

Comment: Yes, ErrorDocument is a directive from Apache, as noted in your link. However, the big problem is that once Apache **delegates** the task to a PHP page (aka, `index.php`), it doesn't know how to come back to the .htaccess to check the ErrorDocument directives. My assumption was PHP and Apache handle the requests parallelly (big mistake, I think)

Comment: I pretty sure that can't be done. But you could, in php, just add `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');include('error/404.php');exit();`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that way, but I finally went for that option, yesterday. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it